# How do you limit access to specific properties of a JPA Entity based on the current role?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, jaas, glassfish-4

I am developing a Java EE business management application using the following technologies:

- JSF
- JPA
- GlassFish 4
- Derby 10.10.1.1

As a start, I created the following objects:

- Person (JPA Entity)

  - Name
  - Address
  - Email
  - etc.
- PersonManager (Stateless EJB)

  - createPerson
  - deletePerson
  - updatePerson
  - findPersonById

I then created the following xhtml pages with backing beans.

- PersonCreater
- PersonViewer
- PersonUpdater

Using JSF and JPA, I found it easy to create the xhtml with backing bean to support creating, viewing and updating my person object.

Using the Java EE Security @RolesAllowed annotation, it was easy to limit access to the PersonManager methods to specific roles, and using the web.xml security-constraint element it was easy to limit JSF page access to specific roles.

I am now to the point where I want to add sensitive information such as social security number to my Person entity, but I only want specific roles to be able to create, read and update the sensitive information.   Is there a standard way to add sensitive information to an entity and then control access?

My fundamental problem is with the PersonManager's getPersonById method.  Currently, this method looks like the following:

```
@RolesAllowed("Reader")
public Person findPersonById(long id) {

    return em.find(Person.class, id);

}
```

If I add the social security number property to the Person entity, the method will return the social security number with the returned Person to all users with role Reader.   Of course, I want everyone to be able to read most of the data associated with my Person object, but I don't want everyone to be able to read the Person's social security number.

I could add logic to the gerPersonById method to remove sensitive information from the Person object based on the current role using the EJBContext's getCallerPrincipal and isCallerInRole methods.   Is this a good way to limit access to the social security property?

I thought about putting all the sensitive information in another entity called PersonSensitive and then creating a OneToOne relationship between Person and PersonSensitive.   However, this leads me back to the problem of how do I limit access to specific entity fields based on the current role.  I tried using @RolesAllowed on the Person entity but this did not work.

I might be able to use some type of inheritance scheme where the sensitive data belongs to a descendant of Person and only specific roles can access the descendant's manager methods.   However, this leads me to creating sets of JSF pages where each set is designated for use by a specific role. Maybe this is the best way to move forward but it seems like it will require much extra work.

Comment: Simply do not connect `Person` and `PersonSensitive` via `OneToOne` (tight coupling anyways) but rather load `PersonSensitive` on demand (via a `@RolesAllowed` application service) only.  The extra work this involves will later pay off due to lesser coupling and fine-grained, well-defined access control improving security.

Comment: Interesting.  I have been considering my Person JPA entity as my top level data object, but I could consider my Person noun as comprising multiple JPA entities such as Person and PersonSensitive.   My PersonManager EJB would control the CRUD transactions on both the entities.   I could use mainly declarative authorization with just a little programmatic authorization.   I will experiment with this technique over the next few days. Thank you for the guidance!